# Parameters are not passing to next state in stateprovider ui router or how i can achieve the same

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am stuck at this issue passing the parameter in state go function but its not going to the next state. Default state parameter values shown in next state Following is my code for passing parameter

```
var params = angular.copy($stateParams);
params[menuItem.params] = menuItem.value;
$state.go('abc.index', params);
```

state params are like this

```
 {orgId: "abc", abType: "ab", Id: "4811989909", request_type: "xyz"}
```

I want it to be like this in the next state

`{orgId: "abc", abType: "ab", Id: "4811989909", request_type: "xyz", new_param: 30}`

How can i achieve this. Please help in the issue.

Comment: What is `menuItem`?

Comment: @Chinni Its a kind of a list containing some parameters

Comment: @ManakBhardwaj, what are you getting actually?